# Increasing transposition table size reduces search speed

Tags: java, arrays, performance, artificial-intelligence, hashtable

I'm writing a Kalah AI for a tournament at my university that I'm going to participate in.
During development, I've stumbled upon some unintuitve behaviour concerning the variation in computation time depending on the size of the transposition table that I cannot explain to myself. Essentially, the problem is the following: increasing the transposition table size reduces the number of positions searched, but does not reduce the amount of time spent on searching these.

#### Transposition Table

A transpostion table is essentially a hash table in which already searched positions and their search results are saved in. This is similar to dynamic programming, where you trade off calculation time for memory.
So intuitively, increasing the memory available should speedup the calculation. Below, you can see the code which governs the transposition table behaviour. (Yes the program is written in java. I know that in C++ things like that would be easier, but the program beeing in java is a requirement for it to participate)

Initialization, called before the search:

```
public TranspositionTable(int power) {
    entries = (int) Math.pow(2, power); 
    table = new Entry[entries];
    hashmask = entries - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        table[i] = new Entry();
        table[i].depth = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Write access:

```
public void add(NodeType type, short value, byte bestMove, byte depth, long hash) {
    int idx = (int) (hash & hashmask);
    Entry tte = table[idx];
    synchronized (tte) {
        if(!tte.used) {
            tte.used = true;
            curEntries++;
            rewrites--;
        }
        //don't overwrite higher search depth entries with lower ones.
        if(tte.depth <= depth){
            rewrites++;
            tte.hash = hash;
            tte.type = type;
            tte.value = value;
            tte.bestMove = bestMove;
            tte.depth = depth;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm currently only using one thread for search, so the synchronized statements are futile at the moment.

Read access:

```
public Entry get(long hash) {
    int idx = (int) (hash & hashmask);
    Entry e = table[idx];
    synchronized (e) {
        if(!e.used) {
            misses++;
            return null; 
        }
        if(hash == e.hash) {
            accesses++;
            return e;
        }
    }
    misses++;
    return null;
}
```

I'm using the 64 bit Jenkins hash function for key generation.

### Search

Calls to the transposition table are made within an iterative deepening, alpha-beta search using aspiration windows, quiesence search and a few other concerning this topic probably irrelevant optimizations. The search procedure somewhat looks like this:

```
public static int search(int alpha, int beta, int stackIdx, MutableState node, int depth, TranspositionTable tt) {
    ...
    long hash = tt.getHash(node);
    Entry e = tt.get(hash);
    if (e != null) {// entry is valid?
        if (e.depth >= depth) {
            switch (e.type) {
            case EXACT:
                ss[stackIdx].pvIdx = e.bestMove;
                return e.value;
            case LOWERBOUND:
                if (e.value > alpha)
                    alpha = e.value;
                break;
            case UPPERBOUND:
                if (e.value < beta)
                    beta = e.value;
                break;
            }
            if (alpha >= beta) {
                ss[stackIdx].pvIdx = e.bestMove;
                return alpha;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    // store node in TT
    NodeType type;
    if (best <= alphaOriginal) {
        type = NodeType.UPPERBOUND;
    } else if (best >= beta) {
        type = NodeType.LOWERBOUND;
    } else {
        type = NodeType.EXACT;
    }
    tt.add(type, (short) bestValue, (byte) bestMove, (byte) depth, hash);
    return best;
}
```

### Search metrics

Selected search and transposition table access metrics are presented below, showing the elapsed time in milliseconds averaged over three runs, amount of positions searched, transposition table used entries, load (used entries divided by total entries), successful accesses, rewrites (overwriting of already used entries) and misses with varying table size captured during a 13 half move deep search from the Kalah(7,7) starting position.

```
table size 2^20:
Passed: 5581 ms
nodesSearched    6_781_473
qsnodesSearched 10_355_860
TT: entries:       966_427
TT: load:        0.9216566
TT: accesses:      426_747
TT: rewrites:    1_479_636
TT: misses:      2_800_001
```

---

```
table size 2^21:
Passed: 5473 ms
nodesSearched    6_571_630
qsnodesSearched 10_156_993
TT: entries:     1_487_042
TT: load:        0.7090769
TT: accesses:      471_566
TT: rewrites:    1_174_011
TT: misses:      2_665_098
```

---

```
table size 2^22:
Passed: 5688  ms
nodesSearched    6_449_400
qsnodesSearched 10_019_367
TT: entries:     1_908_758
TT: load:       0.45508337
TT: accesses:      501_231
TT: rewrites:      863_635
TT: misses:      2_585_731
```

---

```
table size 2^23:
Passed: 5667 ms
nodesSearched    6_380_913
qsnodesSearched  9_945_442
TT: entries:     2_174_936
TT: load:       0.25927258
TT: accesses:      517_884
TT: rewrites:      649_352
TT: misses:      2_538_265
```

---

```
table size 2^24:
Passed: 6015 ms
nodesSearched    6_356_761
qsnodesSearched  9_920_876
TT: entries:     2_329_595
TT: load:       0.13885468
TT: accesses:      526_862
TT: rewrites:      525_318
TT: misses:      2_519_007
```

---

```
table size 2^25:
Passed: 5924 ms
nodesSearched    6_332_790
qsnodesSearched  9_895_421
TT: entries:     2_408_029
TT: load:       0.07176486
TT: accesses:      531_226
TT: rewrites:      457_211
TT: misses:      2_504_210
```

Note:

- There are two types of nodes, quiesence search nodes and "normal" search nodes. Concerning the transposition table, they only differ in the fact that during quiesence search the table is not used to retrieve or store search results.
- Similar results are produced for different starting positions.
- Transposition table initialization is excluded from the time measurement.

As you have probably observed, the amount of nodes searched is reduced with increasing table size, but the time elapsed has not.

My first theory was, that array indexing (calculating the memory address of a specific array entry) in java takes more time with increasing array size, nullifying speedup for having a the smaller search tree by making nodes more expensive to search. But I feel like this is not the case here, as you'd expect some linearity in the search results.

So, my **question** is: what causes the search to take longer when the transposition table size is increased?

Thank you! :)

Comment: for a first question, this is an amazingly good written one! Obviously providing all the classes here would help btw

Comment: Hello @Eugene, thank you a lot! The full code can be found [here](https://gitlab.cs.fau.de/lucareeb/Seedthief/tree/master/src). The transposition table code is in `tt.TranspositionTable`, search is in `search.Search`. The classes `SearchThread` and `Threads` in the package `search` are currently unused. Search results are requested via `frontend.TestInterface`. I hope it helps! :)

Comment: unfortunately it's a lot of code nad I hav very little time to play with this

Comment: It seems likely, that transposition table sizes bigger than the L3 cache actually slows down the algorithm.

Comment: problem is that this a huge data to import into an IDE, understand, profile, etc. I seriously doubt anyone will be doing this - even if it might be interesting.

Comment: Hi, I just found this question when I was trying to find out to what size transposition tables typically grow when searching chess moves, so that I know whether I will be able to fit it in RAM. I was under the impression that you needed exactly one entry for every unique board position you evaluated, leading the size of the transposition table to be out of your control. But here, you seem to choose the size of the transposition table yourself. How does that work? Why isn't the size of your transposition table uniquely determined by the number of unique position you evaluate?